# Is there a way I can overwrite the 'CSS Theme' for my Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, document-body

I want to be able to change the current BODY css to a CSS theme for Halloween. The problem is that my .Net pages are Templates. There must be a way I can get the body class to check if a CSS theme overwrite exists?

Am I able to change the Theme by doing something like this:

**CSS:**

```
/* standard theme */
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-color: #000;
}

/* halloween theme css */
body.halloween {
    background-color: black;
    font-color: #666;
}
```

**Then this placed in the HEAD's editable region:**

```
<%
'CSS Theme overwrite - uncomment if required
 cssTheme = "halloween"
 %>
```

**My BODY tags**

```
<body class="<%=cssTheme%"> 
    content........
</body>
```

I've tried the above but it doesn't work.

Do I need a function doOnLoad() attached to the `<body>` that checks the cssTheme and applies if there is one?

Comment: is it a css file?  Can you replace with a new css file?

Comment: I can, but the `<body>` tag is locked as it's a Template, and the .halloween CSS won't overwrite a css class that's already there

Comment: this is a .net language?  You might be able to get into one of the rendering events in global.asax (or equivalent) and modify the html that is being emited such that the .css has a new name (as long as that .css exists, the browser would then pick it up)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this - the "C" in CSS stands for cascading, which means you can overwrite certain elements of your stylesheets with a more specific definition.

This is illustrated below with a `div` but would work just the same way with a `body` or any other element in HTML. (Note: The javascript is irrelevant, and just used to add the CSS class `Halloween` which you will see defines different presentation rules.)

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $('div').addClass("halloween");  
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:grey,
    color:Black
}

div.halloween{
  background-color:black;
  color:orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Content here
 </div>

<button>make halloween</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

in global.asax.cs - example for c#

```
    void Application_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Response.ContentType == "text/html")
            Response.Filter = new myFilter(Response.Filter);

    }

    class myFilter:System.IO.MemoryStream
    {

        private System.IO.Stream outputStream =null;

        public myFilter(System.IO.Stream output)
        {
            outputStream = output;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {

            var contentInBuffer = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);


            //change the .css here
            contentInBuffer = contentInBuffer.Replace(@"MainDesign.css", @"MainDesign_hallow.css");

            outputStream.Write(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentInBuffer), offset, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(contentInBuffer));
        }

    }
```